# Is it possible to handle 32-bit dependencies without adding foreign architecture to 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, dependencies, 32bit

I want to install an old 64-bit Linux program that depends on some old 32-bit libraries. I don't want to install these old libraries system-wide because other programs won't use them. Also, my package manager can't handle them because some of them are not available in the repositories (even if I add i386 architecture). How can I deal with odd libraries without messing my system? I don't want to add i386 architecture just for these libraries. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> old 64-bit Linux program that depends on some old 32-bit libraries

really?

Spin up a VM running the OS/distribution/version the code last ran on and start from there. You will likely have to do a lot of archaeology to sort out the dependencies.